# Dockerize a Flask REST API with Serverless and DynamoDB

Tags: docker, rest, flask, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework

So what I'm trying to do is to dockerize a Flask REST API that uses Serverless and DynamoDB. I followed [this](https://www.fernandomc.com/posts/developing-flask-based-serverless-framework-apis/) tutorial but it doesn't mention about dockerizing the whole thing. I've also tried to do some research and came up with very minimal resources, like [this](https://medium.com/@janhaviC/restapi-using-flask-and-aws-dynamodb-and-deploying-the-image-to-docker-hub-eff1305c15a) for example.

Is this even possible? If so, some links to guides/advice would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve that with localstack https://github.com/localstack/localstack.
This is assuming that you don't want to have this locally. The services that you mentioned are in the free version of localstack so you should be good to use it.

I think there are some people explaining most of steps a quick search I found  this: https://dev.to/goodidea/how-to-fake-aws-locally-with-localstack-27me

Comment: Let me know if this answered your question :)

Comment: I'll accept it as the answer for now, since it's the closest one